# How to loop through a big matrix and extract the value fast in R?

Tags: r, matrix

With a matrix `docword` with size `4212 * 5000`:

```
0  0  3   1   4  0 
1  1  2   0   0  1
.....
```

I have two long vectors: `docids` and `wordids`:

```
len <- sum(docword)
docids <- array(dim=len)
wordids <- array(dim=len)
```

I wish to iterate the matrix to store the data like this:

```
n = 1
for (i in 1:dim(docword)[1]){
  for (j in 1:dim(docword)[2]){
    for (val in 1:docword[i,j]){ #for each word
      wordids[n] <- j            #store the word id
      docids[n] <- i             #store the doc id
      n = n+1
    }
  }
}
```

Consequently, the expected output of `wordids` and `docids` should be:

```
wordids: (3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,2,3,3,6...)
docids:  (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2....)
```

I wonder is there any faster way to do the same task? Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to end up with? The innermost loop, at least, could be replaced by indexing with a range, e.g. `wordids[n:n+docword[i,j]] <- j`, etc. Masks may be useful in place of the others.

Comment: When the matrix has a value of 0, the inner loop will loop from 1 to 0 (i.e. loop twice); it is not clear that is what you really want. As "alistaire" asked, what is the output you expect ?

Comment: @alistaire I have edited the problem. Is it better?

Comment: @steveb I have edited the question now.

Comment: It seems that "docids" is `rep(row(docword), docword)` and "wordids" is `rep(col(docword), docword)`. These are not in the order in which you scan your "matrix", though, but contain the info you want.

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks for reply. But the order matters in my case

Comment: @user5779223 : I guess you could, just, `order`? `docids = rep(row(docword), docword); wordids = rep(col(docword), docword); o = order(docids); docids = docids[o]; wordids = wordids[o]`

Comment: @alexis_laz Got this error:`> docids = rep(row(docwordmatrix), docwordmatrix)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'` Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @user5779223 : It seems that your `docwordmatrix` is a "data.frame" instead of a "matrix"? If so, use "as.matrix" to convert it to a "matrix".

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks a lot! Please write an answer and I'll accept it.